# Why compiling this Haskell program with -fllvm produces a different result?

Tags: haskell, llvm

Compiling the following program:

```
main = print (sqrt (-7))
```

On OSX Yosemite, LLVM version 3.4.2, target x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, GHC 7.8.4 produces two different results, depending on llvm use:

```
apple1$ ghc -fforce-recomp a.hs -o a; ./a
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )
Linking a ...
NaN

apple1$ ghc -fforce-recomp -fllvm a.hs -o a; ./a
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )
Linking a ...
0.0
```

Why this happens?

Comment: LLVM 3.4 with GHC 7.8.4 and 7.8.3 on x64 linux gives NaN to both.

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? This obviously is/was a bug.

Comment: I would consider it a bug, though it might well have been acceptable according to some specification. LLVM evidently fired some optimisation here which assumes non-negative arguments, making √(-7) undefined behaviour.

Comment: Probably related: [LLVM bug 21048](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21048)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You should post your comment as an answer, so it can be properly upvoted and/or accepted.

Comment: I was merely making a vague guess in _my_ comment. @Ed'ka, _you_ should post that as an answer, you've pointed out the particular bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Question answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@leftaroundabout wrote:

> I would consider it a bug, though it might well have been acceptable according to some specification. LLVM evidently fired some optimisation here which assumes non-negative arguments, making √(-7) undefined behaviour.

@Ed'ka wrote:

> Probably related: [LLVM bug 21048](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21048)